# Rspec tests based on condition

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a Boolean variable `condition`. I have some rspec test cases to check for the presence of an input field.

```
if(condition == true)
   execute the following test cases. 
   it "some test case"
   end
   it "some test case 2"
   end

if(condition == false)
   execute the following test cases. 
   it "some test case 3"
   end
   it "some test case 4"
   end
```

But all test cases are executed. I tried using `context`.

```
context "When condition is true"
  let(:condition) { TRUE }
  it "some test case"
  end
  it "some test case 2"
  end
context "When condition is false"
  let(:condition) { FALSE}
  it "some test case 3"
  end
  it "some test case 4"
  end
```

Please let me know if there any changes to be done either on the syntax or initializing the local variable `condition`.

Comment: Could you please add your code for which you want to run test ?

Comment: Hi, I changed the question format, to show the code. context is the code i want to run. In my case, all the test cases in two context are getting executed, i want only one context to get executed at once based on the boolean value of the variable "condition"

Comment: The `if` should have worked.

Comment: no, it's not working.

Comment: Where is `condition` coming from? Where is it defined? Is it part of your test suite? A global variable? Or a condition in the code you are testing?

Comment: "no, it's not working" - if you say so. You need to post a [mcve] if you want us to help you find out why.

Comment: I declared a variable in the test file say, index.html.haml_spec.rb using let as let(:condition_variable) { TRUE }. This is what I used as a variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `if:` keyword as documented in [RSpec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/filtering/conditional-filters)

```
RSpec.describe "conditional contexts" do
  condition = true
  context "when true", if: condition do
    it 'passes' do
      expect(true).to be_truthy
    end
  end

  condition = false
  context "when false", if: !condition do
    it 'passes' do
      expect(false).to be_falsey
    end
  end

  condition = "non-nil"
  context "will not be run", if: condition.nil? do
    it 'will not get run' do
      expect(nil).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, I tried your example without the non-nil part (only true and false). The problem is the test cases in both context are executing. I am not sure why. This is how I created the variable within the Rspec.describe function. `let(:condition) { true }`. Kindly let me know where I am failing. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It's working now. I just need to know, why we are specifying the condition value as true and false on each context? can't we just assign once as true or false and then check just like a `if{}else{}` condition?

Comment: @ChintuKarthi late answer :) you probably can. It just wants some boolean after `if:`, it can be even something like `if: ENV["foo"] == "bar"`.

Comment: Anyone have an updated documentation link?  The one in this answer seems to no longer work.

Comment: @jayhendren I found this: https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/filtering/if-and-unless/